# Why my custom receiver is not working?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-broadcast

I use parse.com api.

### What my problem is :

When other client send push notification I did not receive anything on my broadcastreceiver.

### My manifest

```
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

  <receiver
      android:name=".MainActivity$MyReceiver"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.yy.xx.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

### and my receiver in mainactivity is here:

```
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public final String TAG = "MyReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

           //this is not working,

        try {
            if (intent == null)
            { 
                Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
            }  
            else 
            {     
                String action = intent.getAction();  
                if (action.equals("com.yy.xx.UPDATE_STATUS"))
                {       
                              //....
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### and my push notification send code is here:

```
  JSONObject obj;
                    try {
                        obj =new JSONObject();  
                        obj.put("action","com.yy.xx.UPDATE_STATUS");
                        obj.put("customdata","message..."); 

                        push_p = new ParsePush();
                        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                        ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();

                        // Notification for Android users
                        //query.whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android");
                        push_p.setQuery(query);
                        push_p.setData(obj); 
                        push_p.setChannel("channel_111"); 

                        push_p.sendInBackground(); 

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I read parse.com api and tutorial but I do not understand what is the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add all this declarations in manifest

```
<!-- PARSE SERVICE AND RECEIVERS -->

    <service
        android:name="com.parse.PushService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
      <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.update.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And add permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: I try it soon and return backto you

Comment: How are sending the push notification ,,the action you send from json should be same as the action declared in the manifest..Example:
<action android:name="com.example.update.UPDATE_STATUS" />

Comment: Oh my friend :) @John you are right , I miss one letter :(( and try mre than 1 day. thanks for your attention

Comment: but the asnwer is not true , comment is true, I just missed one letter different

Comment: could you edşt your answer like your comment(just say action name must be same :D)